# How to make app rotate only when playing videos?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, video, orientation

Im trying to the set the orientation of my app so that it rotates when it is playing a video. Changing the "Supported Interface Orientations" in info.plist changes the orientation for the whole app but I just want it to change orientation when a video is playing. Any ideas of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CoreMotion` to detect the current interface orientation, and the only change interface orientation if your video is playing.

Try checking out the `CMMotionManager` class.

Alternatively, try checking out `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` on your `UIViewController`.